# Python: create "secret id" for usernames

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model:

```
Target(Model):
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKey(User)
```

and also

```
Hunter(Model):
    club = CharField()
```

Hunters should not be able to see the name of the target. Thus I want them to see a secret and anonymous name. Perhaps something like `John Smith => Ao3n(Sn331`

I tried using hashlib to do this:

```
hashlib.md5("targetEmail@hunterClubName".encode()).digest()
```

but then there is no way to reverse the hash to find out who the Target actually is. What would be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this need to be saved in the database or is it just a purely cosmetic thing you're trying to do? What happens when you have 2 John Smiths, should they have the same anon name?

Comment: If I have 2 John Smiths, they will have unique emails, which are used to generate the secret id. This is purely for display in the frontend via DRF. It is not to be stored in the DB.

Answer (score -1):

```
secret_id=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Will that work?

Comment: same problem as above. it is not unique for every target-hunter combination